# Openstack autopilot-Firewall pending create

Tags: juju, landscape, openstack-autopilot

We have installed open stack autopilot and in dashboard created firewall and the status showing pending create.how i can delete the same and how to find the neutron database in which LXD its installed to delete it from databse using juju management

Regards
Aathi

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following for the official word on the Openstack "Autopilot" offering in the Landscape tool:

https://insights.ubuntu.com/2014/11/06/putting-your-openstack-on-autopilot/

Specifically, Here is the text from Canonical:

> Thanks for your interest in Ubuntu OpenStack. Canonical has sunsetted
>   OpenStack Autopilot and replaced it with [conjure-up](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/try-openstack). We welcome you to
>   visit our [OpenStack product page](https://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/openstack) to find an Ubuntu OpenStack solution
>   that meets your needs.